# Python is recognising an Int as a List when using =%

Tags: python, list, sorting, int, radix

I am attempting to create a radix sort in python. So far this is my code:

```
i = 0
numbers = "random_numbers10.txt"
numbersAsString = open(numbers)
numbersList = [int(i) for i in numbersAsString]

thisList = numbersList
bins = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
divisor = 10


for y in range(0,10):
    for x in range(0, len(thisList)):
        c = numbersList[x]
        c %= divisor
        thisList[x] = c
    for n in range(0, len(thisList)):
        if thisList[n] == n:
            bins[n].append(numbersList)
    for m in range(0, 10):
        for o in range(0, len(bins[m])):
            numbersList.append(bins[m])




for i in numbersList:
    print(numbersList[i])
```

Unfortunately on the line c %= divisor python throws a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %=: 'list' and 'int'

if I print either c or numbersList[x] is comes out as the expected number from my list of numbers. Is there any reason that an integer that is a member of the list would be recognised as a list itself? Or could it be an issue with my fourth line of code? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't ever find yourself doing this in Python -- `bins = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]`. You're just asking for off-by-1 errors and other nasty, difficult to debug problems. It's not C. You don't have to initialize anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
for m in range(0, 10):
    for o in range(0, len(bins[m])):
        numbersList.append(bins[m])
```

This doesn't look right to me. You iterate through `o` but never use it. As-is, you are adding lists to `numbersList` rather than integers. Did you mean:

```
for m in range(0, 10):
    for o in range(0, len(bins[m])):
        numbersList.append(bins[m][o])
```

Or, as Ilja suggests, you could shorten it to:

```
for m in range(0, 10):
    numbersList.extend(bins[m])
```

Comment: You could simplify even more to `for bin in bins: numberList.extend(bin)`. There are a bunch of logic errors in the code too, but this solves the `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a shallow copy of the numbers list:

```
thislist = numbersList
```

This line means that thislist *points* to numbersList, it is not a separate entity or a copy.

When your code reaches the m range, you change the numbersList by appending items. This is changing thislist too.

```
thislist = numbersList[:]
```

Changing this has fixed the value error but now you will notice a load of empty bins on the end of numbersList. It won't print using the for loop at the end of your example.

Note that the sorting algorithm doesn't seem to be working either, at least in my example One problem is solved and another is found!

Comment: Where does *You have made a shallow copy of the numbers list* tie in with *it is not a separate entity or copy*?